# If an integral of a product of a function and an arbtrary bump function around $t$ is $0$, $f(t)=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, definite-integrals

In my physics textbook, it is stated that if $\displaystyle \int_{t-\delta}^{t+\delta} b(x)f(x)dx=0$ for all bump function $b$ whose support $supp(b)\subset [t-\delta,t+\delta]$ and $f$ is a continuous function, then $f(t)=0$.
Is it true? If it is true, could you give me information about the proof? I'd also like to know that if $\displaystyle \int_{t-\delta}^{t+\delta} \int_{t-\delta}^{t+\delta} b(x,y)f(x,y)dxdy=0$ for all bunmp function $b$ whose support $supp(b)\subset [t-\delta,t+\delta]\times [t-\delta,t+\delta]$ and f is a countinuous function, then $f(t,t)=0$?

Comment: I believe this requires $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: ah, sorry. I forgot to say that..... I'm physicist and bad at mathmatics.... I'll edit.

Comment: As a fellow physicist, I too know the temptation to assume all functions are as well-behaved as you want them to be.

Answer (score 1):

I'll discuss the 1-d case only. The 2-d case is identical in spirit.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $f(t) > 0$. ($f(t)<0$ can be handled similarly.) Then there is a small neighborhood $(t-\epsilon, t+\epsilon)$ around $t$ such that $f(\tau) > 0$ for all $\tau\in(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)$. Moreover, we can choose $\epsilon>0$ to be as small as we like while maintaining this condition.

In particular, let's take $0 < \epsilon < \delta$. We next pick a bump function $b$ supported in $(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)$ with $b(\tau) > 0$ for all $\tau\in(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)$. (If you want to know how to pick such a bump function, pick your favorite bump function which is everywhere positive, then rescale and translate.) Then we have
$$
0 = \int_{t-\delta}^{t+\delta} b(\tau)f(\tau)d\tau \geq \int_{t-\epsilon}^{t+\epsilon} b(\tau)f(\tau)d\tau > 0
$$
where the first equality comes from the hypothesis on $f$ and the last inequality is because $b(\tau)f(\tau)>0$ on $(t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon)$. This is a contradiction, and thus we conclude that $f(t) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for so nice explanations! It is really clear and easy to understand!!